# Stop NSView from printing

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have a very basic Mac application in Xcode with a Split View that contains a PDFThumbnailView and a PDFView. (Just like Preview.)

There's hardly any Swift code beyond what is required to load a PDF into the views.

However, when I select Print from the Print menu, the app wants to print the ThumbnailView, unless I click on the PDFView first.

Is there any way to always make it print the PDFView and never the ThumbnailView? I presume it's a setting or parameter somewhere in the Storyboard, rather than a bit of code as such.

Xcode 10.2.1 on Mojhave 10.14.5.

Comment: Are you using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontroller to print?

Comment: Unlikely, since it's an app for MacOS, not iOS. (Have clarified that in the OP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to provide your own print method (like `printContent:`) on your controller, and in your XIB file change the target method for the print menu item to `printContent:` instead of `print:`

```swift
// eg.
@IBOutlet weak var pdfThumbnails: PDFThumbnailView!
@IBOutlet weak var pdfContent: PDFView!

...

@IBAction func printContent(_ sender: Any) {
   self.pdfContent.printView(sender)
}
```