# NSViews insist on printing - how to disable this?

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, nsview

I have a single-windowed LSUIElement application ("status menu" app, lacking a menu bar) on App Store.

I wanted my app to print, so I added a printing capability in XCode. Printing is done by the application delegate, triggered by a menu item. This works fine.

Sadly, now every NSView everywhere has printing triggered by cmd-P. This includes NSTableViews, NSTextFields, NSTextViews etc. For instance, press Cmd-P (which isn't even in the status menu) while in a search field, and it wants to print itself.

I find virtually no info on this behavior. Surely it's possible to disable this? Otherwise each and every interface element that gets into the responder chain has to be subclassed. Subclassing NSSearchField doesn't even work (the subclass implementation of print: isn't called but it prints anyway).

Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Duplicate of [Stop NSView from printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144096/stop-nsview-from-printing)

Comment: Similar, but the LSUIElement detail (with a menu bar in the .xib whose keyboard shortcuts are triggered even though the menu bar is never shown) makes this case a bit different IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had a main menu bar with cmd-P shortcuts left in the .xib file, with the usual print commands directed to the first responder. Removing the menu bar (which was never shown) cured the unwanted print behavior.